# How to delete each number at the beginning of a line in Notepad or Microsoft Word?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, text-editing, notepad

I have a list like this:

```
1 http://
2 http://
3 http://
4 http://
5 http://
```

I would like to remove 1,2,3,4,5 without doing this manually for each line. The only tool I am using is notepad in a bare Windows setup.

How can i remove this in Notepad or Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 13):

In Microsoft Word, use Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>) with:

```
<[0-9]@ (http)
```

replace with:

```
\1
```

Make sure "Use wildcards" is enabled.

Comment: +1 I use Linux so much I'd never bothered to try text edits in Office/Windows.

Comment: Oh, nice to know you can do more than just *.

Comment: Holy cow, you can do backreferences in Word??!  Where is this documented?

Comment: @Gregg: [Here.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/putting-regular-expressions-to-work-in-word-HA001087304.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001087305)

Comment: @grawity: Holy cow indeed. By the way, the link seems to be broken.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT.: [updated link](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-US/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f)

Answer (score 3):

Using Notepad++ text editor you can use Column mode selection.
Press Alt before select the text you want to delete an it allows you select a column (instead the complete rows of the selection)
Also Notepad++ has a portable version and is not necessary to install anything to do this.

Comment: +1 for Notepad++. My favorite text editor and I can barely live without it!

Answer (score 0):

i used excel 2013. when you paste in excel, first column would be filled with number and remaining content in second column. then you can just copy second column. but you will be left with extra spaces between each lines. then you can go to find and go to special, select blank rows and delete those rows.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the options... you can also select as a column in MS Word by holding ALT+SHIFT and dragging.